# Penetration test in a staging environment. When and how much?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-design, test-automation-framework, penetration

We certainly all know the discussion when penetration testing makes sense. In a staging scenario, the test scenario can be interesting to use there to perform a penetration test. And, of course, also in production.

But yesterday we had a discussion in the team how often we want to test our projects via CI pipeline and vulnerability scanner for issues.

The discussion resulted in a violent exchange of blows.

- As little scanning as possible. Only once a week would make sense to
  integrate the high risk issues into the respective sprint.
- Permanent scanning via CI integration. But here the risk was described that one would find possibly too many false positives, which would go beyond any sprint planning.
- Possible drop in performance if several pages are scanned at the same time. This scenario is also not impossible and I have experienced it in other projects. Scanning some pages took days.

Do you have a meaningful strategy how and when to use penetration testing in an agile staging scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'm more in favor of static code analyzers (e.g. Sonarqube) which also inspect code for some common OWASP issues once per sprint.